# made with a and b (exclusive)?

Tags: conjunctions

If one makes a product with method A and a different product with method B, then is it correct to say that 'Two products are made with A and B.'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated it would be ambiguous, you could add the word "respectively" to make the meaning entirely clear:

"Two products are made with A and B, **respectively**"

Here the adverb "respectively" means "considered individually or in turn, and in the order mentioned".

Comment: thank you for the answer. If a data is processed with method A and method B so that two different outcomes are obtained, then can I say 'A data is processed with method A and B respectively.' the same way ?

Comment: Yes, although data is plural in English (the singular is datum) so there is no article, however you'll often find it acceptable (but technically wrong) to use a singular verb "The data is collected". "Data are processed with method A and B respectively" could mean you took the data and processed it with A, and then you took the same data and processed it with B. Although in this case it could also mean A followed by B, as it's not connecting one thing (a datum) to one thing (a method), but one thing (the dataset) to two things (method a and method b). I would probably reword it.

Comment: @james Yes, I would suggest something along the lines of "Processing the data set using method A produced result Alpha and using method B produced result Beta". My personal preference is, usually, to sacrifice brevity for clarity if there is any conflict at all.